# How to implement XSLTSearch in an umbraco

Tags: xslt, search, umbraco

How to implement XSLTSearch package in an umbraco website, can anyone answer step by step?

Comment: On SO people do not "answer step by step" when you have shown no effort to solve the problem. Please read the [faq] and [ask] to understand the guidelines for posting here.

Comment: this is like asking, "how to code using X technology" kind of question ..  Please vote to close. Not a real question!

Comment: I disagree. It is a badly worded question but it is asking how to implement something, not how to code something. In the context of Umbraco, I think this has a valid use for other developers needing some info on the options for implementing an XSLT search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several good resources for this but personally I would try something out of the box first. [XSLTSearch](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/xsltsearch), created by Douglas Robar is a good package that can be installed straight into Umbraco.

If you need help on installing packages or using XSLT in Umbraco I would advise visiting [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org/) for help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Digbyswift. I implimented XSLT search and its working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start if you want to roll your own:  [How To make Search for Umbraco site with Lucene.Net, Examine and XSLT](http://maanehunden.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/how-i-made-umbraco-search-with-lucene-indexing-eximine-and-xslt/)

Or, take @Digbyswift's advice and try [XSLTSearch](http://www.percipientstudios.com/xsltsearch/overview.aspx).